# Get DropDownList selected value

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I have a **DropDownList** that I fill on **Page_Load**. When I try to get the selected value `string id = myDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();` Every time I only got the 1st Value, but when I change the value of the DropDownList and check for the **string id** It always shows my the 1st value.

This is my Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (commesseDataSource.Count != 0)
        {
            initComboCommesse();
        }

        if (Session["Matricola"] != null)
            matricolaDip = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Matricola"]);

        if (Session["LivLogin"] != null)
            livlogin = Convert.ToInt32(Session["Matricola"]);

    }
```

this Is how I bind the DropDown

```
private void initComboCommesse()
    {
        myDropDownList.DataTextField = "Value";
        myDropDownList.DataValueField = "Key";
        myDropDownList.DataSource = commesseDataSource;
        myDropDownList.DataBind();
    }
```

I've already tried to

```
 protected void myDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string id = myDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString(); // I always get the 1st value of the Drop Down
 }
```

And also

```
 protected void myDropDownList_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string id = myDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString(); // I always get the 1st value of the Drop Down
 }
```

But none of these had worked, I would like to know how to get the selected value of the DropDownList, every time I selected a new value In the DropDownList

Comment: also update your question with drop down markup

Comment: @ArunPratap You would like to know how I fill the Drop Down?

Comment: @ChangeWorld can u tell me which value store in database int or string?

Comment: You may want to do some searching; this is a common problem. It's usually due to not checking for `IsPostBack` in `Page_Load` before refilling the drop down list.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yess Nicely done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

When You Insert In your DropDownList Value In Database then you need to change:

```
string id = myDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value.ToString();
```